# AWS RDS Postgres threshold

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

For AWS RDS Postgres what would be following thresholds for:
1. Maximum Table Size Limit 
2. Maximum Number of Columns that can be inserted into a table
3. Maximum size of each column in a table.

Answer (score 0):

I believe AWS RDS wont have any special limitations. It will just depend on the underlying postgres version you are using. Please check the standard Postgres documentation.
Please see the link below:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/limits.html

Max table size:32 TB
Max columns per table: 1600
Max field size: 1 GB

Comment: Link only answer will lose its value when the link is broken in future, please add the relevant context from the link into answer.